# Android Malware Dataset

Tags: malware, android

I am working on a project to identify the author of the malicious apk. To test my results I need dataset of malicious apks along with their authors. Currently I am working on a dataset which is very small. Could anyone please suggest some resources so that I can have a good amount of malicious apks along with their authors to evaluate my results ?

Comment: Questions of the type "where can I find X?" are off-topic as the answers could go on forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another reasonably useful dataset that i've come across is:

- AndroMalShare - http://sanddroid.xjtu.edu.cn:8080/ (The domain name has changed at some point but can be found also at http://202.117.54.231:8080/#home ... and if not, the project seems to go as "AndroMalShare Project" ... so just Google that)

Answer (score 2):

The malware genome project manages a huge amount of malware samles that is also categorized. If combined with your data set, you might as well be able to identify authors.

You can request access [here.](http://www.malgenomeproject.org/)

Other resources for malware samples are

- contagio malware dump - http://contagiodump.blogspot.ca/
- M0Droid - http://m0droid.netai.net/modroid/

Comment: Thanks mate!! Do you have any suggestions regarding how to classify an apk according to it's author/developer. The above malware dataset is categorised as per malware families.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not use the malware set myself yet, so I cannot provide immediate help here, sorry. I heard of works that identify malware from the same (group of) authors by some similarity measures between the malware binaries, but those might be purely academic approaches. However, this might be an interesting question on its own, so feel free to post a follow up question to clarify whether such a thing is possible or has been done before.

Answer (score 0):

Canadian Institute of Cybersecurity has large collection of malware datasets and some of them are Android specific.  https://www.unb.ca/cic/datasets/index.html